# if Checkbox is Checked, then Add Value to Input Field

Tags: javascript, function, input, checkbox

i'm trying to change the value of an text input to no if checked or yes if not checked, this with a checkbox but i cant seem to get it working..

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="" />
<input type="text" name="text" id="text" value="" />


$(function(){
$('#checkbox').change(function() {
    $("#text").val(($(this).is(':checked')) ? "yes" : "no");
});
});
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/YJRQp/

is there something i miss here? please advise.

Comment: JQuery isn't included in that fiddle...

Comment: It works fine. Seems you forget to include `jQUery`.

Comment: You didn't load jquery! No wonder that it did not work...

see here: `http://jsfiddle.net/YJRQp/1/`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to include jQuery in your fiddle.  Theres a dropdown on the left for libraries.

Comment: i feel ashamed for missing that ! sorry

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#checkbox").click(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $("#text").val("Yes");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#text").val("No");
        }
    });
});
```